# ¿Cuál es el significado de utilizar el símbolo de interrogación (?) dentro de un WHERE en una consulta SQL y PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Quería saber para que se utiliza el símbolo de `?` en una consulta `sql`.

- Aquí un ejemplo con `PHP` y `SQL`:

```php
    <?php
        foreach($nuevoArreglo as $row){
                    $row = (int) trim($row);
                    $sql="SELECT G300CTA FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 WHERE G300CTA = ?";
                    $stid = $conn->prepare($sql);

                    if($stid->execute(array($row))){
                        # EL WHILE IRA MOVIENDO FILA POR FILA     
                        while($result = $stid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            $cuenta[] = $result['G300CTA'];
                        }
                        $stid->closeCursor();
                    }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

el `?` dentro de una consulta se utiliza como `marcador` para luegor ligarlo a un parametro

ejemplo:

```
/* crear una sentencia preparada */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=? and id =?")) {

    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores  */
/* en este caso tipo string por el `s` y int con `i`*/
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $city,$id);

    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* ligar variables de resultado */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);

    /* obtener valor */
    $stmt->fetch();

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* cerrar sentencia */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

**referencia:**
[bind-param](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Recuerda es marcador de posición

Answer (score 0):

El signo de interrogación representa un parámetro que luego será reemplazado.

Ejemplo:

```
insert into tabla (campo1, campo2,campo3) values(?,?,?);

select * from tabla where id = ?;
```

Comment: Lo que aquí veo es sql puro y shi no aplica tu respuesta, revisa bien

Answer (score 0):

Sentencias preparadas y procedimientos almacenados.

Muchas de las bases de datos más maduras admiten el concepto de sentencias preparadas. Estas pueden definirse como un tipo de plantillas compiladas para SQL que las aplicaciones quieren ejecutar, pudiendo ser personalizadas utilizando parámetros variables.

Obtener datos empleando sentencias preparadas

Este ejemplo obtiene datos basándose en un valor de clave proporcionado por un formulario. La entrada del usuario es entrecomillada automáticamente, con lo cual no hay riesgo de un ataque por inyección de SQL.

```
<?php
$sentencia = $mbd->prepare("SELECT * FROM REGISTRY where name = ?");
if ($sentencia->execute(array($_GET['name']))) {
  while ($fila = $sentencia->fetch()) {
    print_r($fila);
  }
}
?>
```

Aquí está la explicación: https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php